# Quick head/tail command question

Tags: command, tail, head

This is the output from the file I'm using:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
iiiii
jjjjj
```

I know using `tail -n 5 filename` will display this:

```
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
iiiii
jjjjj
```

How do I use the `head` command in such a way to display the same *exact* lines?

`head -n 10 filename | tail -n 5 filename` works, but that's just redundant for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you mean the last five lines, or lines 6-10?

Comment: Why do you want to use only `head`?  Why do you think `head` can do this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You want to display the line _numbers_? Or you want to use head to show the same lines that tail did?

Comment: @Otheus My bad, I'm looking for the latter. I want `head` to print out the same exact lines as `tail` did.

Comment: Using `head` to print the tail of a file instead of using `tail` is nonsensical at best. It may nor be clear with a small file like in your example, but what if the file is 50MiB of text? Do you still want lines 6-10, or do you want the last 5 lines in the file?

Answer (score 2):

Your command

```
head -n 10 filename | tail -n 5 filename
```

is nonsensical.  The output of `head` will never be read by `tail` as `tail` is already reading directly from `filename`.  Therefore, the result is exactly the same as with just

```
tail -n 5 filename
```

The `head` utility is used to get a certain number of lines from the *top* of the file (or, with GNU `head`, all lines of the file except for a certain number of lines counting from the end of the file). The `head` utility is not what you want to use to get the tail end of a file's data.  For that, use `tail` as you have shown.

Any other solution would be more complex than your basic `tail -n 5`.

For example:

```
tac filename | head -n 5 | tac
```

which assumes that one has `tac` from GNU coreutils installed. Both `head` and `tail` will be installed on any system that has an even remotely POSIX compliant shell environment, while `tac` will only be found on Linux systems and other systems where GNU coreutils has been installed.

Or, you could implement your own `tail` in `awk` if it's `tail` that you just don't want to use:

```
$ awk -vn=5 '{ lines[i++ % n] = $0 } END { for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) print lines[(i+j)%n] }' filename
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
iiiii
jjjjj
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you want.

```
foo@bar~$ cat file 
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd
eeeee
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
iiiii
jjjjj
```

You want to use `head` to print out the same exact lines as `tail` did.

```
foo@bar~$ tail -n 5 file 
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
iiiii
jjjjj
```

**Solution**

```
foo@bar~$ sort -r file | head -5 | sort
fffff
ggggg
hhhhh
iiiii
jjjjj
```

Comment: `tac file | head -5 | tac` also does the same job

Answer (score 0):

This implementation uses `head` without `tail` to display only the last 5 lines of the file.

```
head -n -0 filename | sed 1,$(echo "$(wc -l filename | awk '{ print $1 }')-5" | bc -l)d
```

> head -n -0 filename -- Displays all the lines in the file.

From `man head:`

-n, --lines=[-]N
              print the first N lines instead of the first 10; with the leading ‘-’, print all but the last N lines of each file

> $(echo "$(wc -l filename | awk '{ print $1 }')-5" | bc -l) -- Calculates the number of lines to delete based on the total number of lines in the file minus 5.
>
> sed 1,(NUMBER_OF_LINES_TO_DELETE)d -- Removes all but the last 5 lines based on the previous calculation.

Answer (score -1):

`head` is for getting the first *n* lines of a file. `tail` is for getting the last *n* lines of a file. If you want something more general-purpose, you can check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022384/bash-tool-to-get-nth-line-from-a-file).